# Material-UI + React-test-renderer + React-Router + Tabs/Tab component and Modal component

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui, react-test-renderer, react-forwardref

I'm working on a React project right now (I'm a React newbie btw...).

Stack:

- "react": "^17.0.1"
- "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2"
- "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
- "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"

I have a Tab layout (using Tabs and Tab component from Material-UI) as below:

```
const TabLayout = props => {
  const {
    tabs, authenticated, authorized, signInPath,
    unauthorizedPath
  } = props
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const location = useLocation()

  return (<>
          <AppBar className={classes.bar}>
            <Box className={classes.barDiv}>
              <Tabs value={location.pathname} className={classes.tabs}>
                {tabs.map(tab => (
                    <Tab key={tab.key} value={tab.to} label= {t(tab.label, tab.key)} component={Link} to={tab.to} className={classes.tab}/>
                ))}
              </Tabs>
              <div className={classes.rightBar}>
                <div className={classes.rightBarElement}>
                  <img alt="xxx" height="28px" src="xxx.png" className={classes.logo} />
                </div>
                <UserInfo className={classes.rightBarElement} />
              </div>
            </Box>
          </AppBar>
          <Box className={classes.content}>
            <Switch>
              {tabs.map(tab => (
                  <PrivateRoute key={tab.key} path={tab.to} render={tab.render}
                                authenticated={authenticated}
                                authorized={authorized}
                                noAuthRedirect={signInPath}
                                noPermRedirect={unauthorizedPath} />
              ))}
              <Route render={() => <Redirect to="/scenario" />} />
            </Switch>
          </Box>
          <Footer />
      </>
  )
}
```

Everything works fine, the console is empty, the UX and UI look as desired but...

I try to add a snapshot test using react-test-renderer, like below:

```
  it('should render correclty', () => {
    const elem = renderer.create(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Provider store={mockStore(initialStore)}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <App/>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>).toJSON()
    expect(elem).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
```

Unfortunately I get these errors:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error
      The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Tabs)> component:
      
          at Tabs (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Tabs/Tabs.js:120:24)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Tabs)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at div
          at Styled(MuiBox) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/styled/styled.js:95:28)
          at header
          at Paper (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Paper/Paper.js:55:23)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at AppBar (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar.js:114:23)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at TabLayout (/home/projectDir/src/layouts/TabLayout/TabLayout.js:73:5)
          at Route (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:470:29)
          at Switch (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:676:29)
          at Routes (/home/projectDir/src/Routes.js:16:11)
          at Loading (/home/projectDir/src/views/Loading/Loading.js:14:5)
          at Connect(Loading) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:233:41)
          at App (/home/projectDir/src/App.js:16:45)
          at ThemeProvider (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:48:24)
          at Provider (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js:21:20)
          at Router (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:99:30)
          at BrowserRouter (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.js:67:35)
      
      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10989:23)
      at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11022:5)
      at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3662:12)
      at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3683:9)
      at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11855:11)
      at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14443:7)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11391:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)

    console.error
      The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Modal)> component:
      
          at Modal (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Modal/Modal.js:92:36)
          at Popover (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Popover/Popover.js:116:22)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at Menu (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Menu/Menu.js:65:32)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at UserInfo (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@cosmotech/ui/dist/index.cjs.js:575:5)
          at WithStyles(UserInfo) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at div
          at div
          at Styled(MuiBox) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/styled/styled.js:95:28)
          at header
          at Paper (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Paper/Paper.js:55:23)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at AppBar (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/core/AppBar/AppBar.js:114:23)
          at WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.js:67:31)
          at TabLayout (/home/projectDir/src/layouts/TabLayout/TabLayout.js:73:5)
          at Route (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:470:29)
          at Switch (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:676:29)
          at Routes (/home/projectDir/src/Routes.js:16:11)
          at Loading (/home/projectDir/src/views/Loading/Loading.js:14:5)
          at Connect(Loading) (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:233:41)
          at App (/home/projectDir/src/App.js:16:45)
          at ThemeProvider (/home/projectDir/node_modules/@material-ui/styles/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js:48:24)
          at Provider (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js:21:20)
          at Router (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router/cjs/react-router.js:99:30)
          at BrowserRouter (/home/projectDir/node_modules/react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.js:67:35)
      
      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10989:23)
      at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11022:5)
      at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3662:12)
      at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3683:9)
      at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11855:11)
      at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14443:7)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11391:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)

  ● App test suite › should render correclty

    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

      81 |
      82 |   it('should render correclty', () => {
    > 83 |     const elem = renderer.create(
         |                           ^
      84 |         <BrowserRouter>
      85 |           <Provider store={mockStore(initialStore)}>
      86 |             <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

      at Tabs (node_modules/@material-ui/core/Tabs/Tabs.js:166:32)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6016:18)
      at updateForwardRef (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8038:20)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10015:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13800:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13728:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13691:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13404:18)
      at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2537:26
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
      at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2486:10)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2532:9)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2519:3)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13004:9)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16454:3)
      at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17149:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:83:27)
```

I read like hundred pages through the Web but I cannot figure out how to solve this...

I read the React documentation, the Material-UI documentation, threads on Stackoverflow,...

I tried to "wrap" Tabs component by using React.forwardRef() and add ref={ref} in props but no success (same thing for Tab and Link).

For the error "The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Modal)> component" I guess its due to Menu and MenuItem use...

Ok it's a ref problem, but from who? Material-UI, react-renderer-test, my code ?
I'm kind of lost and I will REALLY appreciate your help ;)

Thanks a lot!